# update method returns null value for complex objects in play framework 2

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sql-update, playframework-2.2

Play framework 2 update() method acts weirdly in my project.

My project has following model classes:

```
@entity
public class Images{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Lob
    public byte[] imageFile;
}


@entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    public Blobs photo;
}
```

This is index.scala.html:

```
@(user : Users)
<p>@user.id</p>
<p>@user.name</p>
<p>@user.photo.id</p> 
<a href="@routes.Application.editUser(1L)">edit user no. 1</a>
```

And this is the code in my editUser.scala.html:

```
@(id : Long, userForm : Form[Users])
@form(action = routes.Application.update(id))
@inputText(userForm("name"))
@inputText(userForm("photo.id"))
<input type="submit" value="UPDATE">
```

Here's my controller class:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(Users.find.byId(1L)));
    }

    public static Result editUser(Long id) {
        Form<Users> userForm = form(Users.class).fill(Users.find.byId(id));
            return ok(
        views.html.editUser.render(id, userForm)
    );
   }

    public static Result update(Long id) {
        Form<Users> userForm = form(Users.class).bindFromRequest();
        userForm.get().update(id);
        return redirect((routes.Application.index()));
    }

}
```

Assume that there is one entry in Blobs class with id=1 and a blob and there is one entry in Users class also with id=1. Now I want to update that user and set the photo id from the Blobs table.

The problem is when I try to update user from editUser form and refer back to index.scala.html, I get a null pointer exception. It seems update() method just returns null for photo field in Users form, though it has no problem updating name value of the user. I checked with userForm.field("photo").value() and it seems that bindFromRequest works properly. But after updating, the `photo` field is just null. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Edit:
P.S: This program will begin with a null pointer exception, because photo field of Users is null at the beginning of the program. Just assume we go directly to the edit page and we try to update `Users` with a `photo` from Blobs. The problem is even after the update, I get null pointer exception and it seems update doesn't affect that field in `User` class

Comment: Can you post the index method of your controller?

Comment: Done. Index method was added to edited post